# Xamarin Forms bind to parent property in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having trouble binding to a property in Xamarin, and can't figure it out using Microsoft's documentation for some reason.

Say I have this viewmodel:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Foos { get; set; }

    public string SpecialFoo { get; set; }
}
```

And this in my view:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding SpecialFoo}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

I am running into the problem that in the DataTemplate, I can't make the binding to a property inside FooViewModel. How do I make this binding to SpecialFoo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's easy all you need is a reference to your page and tell it that look for this in the VM and not in the model:

Give your current ContentPage a name :

```
<ContentPage 
...
x:Name="currentPage"/>
```

Then your label would look something like:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding BindingContext.SpecialFoo, Source={x:Reference currentPage}}"/>
```

Comment: My hero! This has been driving me mad all morning, thanks.

Comment: Happy to help :)